# updating student information in symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony

I am developping an application and I got a problem in my front-end part. It's related to **Symfony** and **Ajax**. So I am using a session variable in order to add a student to a school before sending the form of school to the server (back-end). I am using then some Ajax. I do not how to debug it. I tried what it is posted in the net but it does not work. I was able to add a student to a school but I was not able to update the student information. That's seem easy but it's not as I thought. Here is an ajax call that I am using in my **SchoolCreate.html.twig**:

```
function ajax () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ path('student_add') }}",
            data: $('#addStudent').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                var htmlToDisplay = response.trim();
                $('#students').html(htmlToDisplay);
            }
        });
    }
```

My modal used to create school:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:School:addStudent')) }}
</div>
```

**addStudent**:

```
public function addStudentAction(Request $request) {
    $student = new Student();
    $form =  $this->createForm(StudentType::class, $student);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');

    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
      $session = $request->getSession();
      $student = $form->getData();
      if ($session->has('students'))
          $students = $session->get('students');
      $students[] = $student;
      $session->set('$students', $students);
      $template = $this->renderView('AppBundle:School:StudentList.html.twig', array(
            'students' => $students
        ));
        return new Response($template);
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Student:StudentAdd.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
    }
```

I try to do the same in updateStudent function but I got a problem related to 30 second exceeded and I do not know how to debug in Ajax. I define my bottom of update inside **StudentList.html.twig**
Thanks,

Comment: for ajax you should use fos js routing do you know that bundle ?

Comment: @Mintho433 no I do not know this bundle, but I think it is impossible for me to use it, Unfortunately, it's not my choice. I could not use external library and this library is not made by default in my project

Comment: expose `addStudentAction` action, and check with chrome console for sure route is correct.